# Add row to top of table after headers

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add new data to a table with a form. I have it adding data at the bottom of the sheet.

I want the new info at the top.

With my code, it sends the data to two sheets, the "home" sheet and the sheet that is selected in the first combo box.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
TargetSheet = ComboBox1.Value
If TargetSheet = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
Worksheets(TargetSheet).Activate
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Value = TextBox3.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 4).Value = TextBox4.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 5).Value = TextBox5.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 6).Value = TextBox6.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 7).Value = TextBox7.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 8).Value = TextBox8.Value

Worksheets("Home").Activate
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = ComboBox1.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = TextBox1.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Value = TextBox2.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 4).Value = TextBox3.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 5).Value = TextBox4.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 6).Value = TextBox5.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 7).Value = TextBox6.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 8).Value = TextBox7.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 9).Value = TextBox8.Value
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 10).Value = Date
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 11).Value = TimeValue(Now)
ActiveSheet.Cells(lastrow + 1, 12).Value = TextBox9.Value

MsgBox ("Item Added Successfully.")
TextBox1.Value = ""
TextBox2.Value = ""
TextBox3.Value = ""
TextBox4.Value = ""
Worksheets("Home").Activate
Worksheets("Home").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

How do I put the new data in the second row since I have headers on the sheet?

Comment: Is it an [Excel structured table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but I haven't used the table formatting on Excel. I've only used cell formatting on the headers so that there's borders and a coloured fill, otherwise no structure.

Comment: And you want the values to be added at the top of both sheets?

Comment: Preferably yes if that is possible

Comment: Do you already know what's the row number at the top? like 1 or 2? could it change? is it the same in both sheets?

Comment: I would like the data to add in row 2 since I have headers. My vision is for the data to be added into row 2 and then move all the rows down. I don't know if that answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of stuff to improve <s>your</s> my code, but I want to keep it simple

Some things to begin:

1. Use [option explicit](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) so you don't have unexpected behavior with undefined variables
2. Always indent your code (see [www.rubberduckvba.com](http://www.rubberduckvba.com) a free tool that helps you with that)
3. Try to separate your logic defining variables and the reusing them
4. [Name](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2006/12/14/naming-userform-controls/) your forms' controls
5. Check a [great article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) about UserForms (when you feel you're ready to advance)

Check the code's comments, and adapt it to fit your needs

**EDIT:** No need for the EntireRow qualifier as we are already selecting the whole row, and added the copy format from below

**Code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ' Define object variables
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim homeSheet As Worksheet

    Dim targetSheetName As String
    Dim homeSheetName As String

    Dim targetSheetTopRow As Long
    Dim homeSheetTopRow As Long

    Dim textBox1Value As Variant
    Dim textBox2Value As Variant
    Dim textBox3Value As Variant
    Dim textBox4Value As Variant
    Dim textBox5Value As Variant
    Dim textBox6Value As Variant
    Dim textBox7Value As Variant
    Dim textBox8Value As Variant
    Dim textBox9Value As Variant

    ' Define parameters
    targetSheetTopRow = 2
    homeSheetTopRow = 2
    homeSheetName = "Home"

    ' Validate if combobox has any value
    If Me.ComboBox1.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    ' Get target sheet name
    targetSheetName = Me.ComboBox1.Value

    ' Add a reference to sheets
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(targetSheetName)
    Set homeSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(homeSheetName)

    ' Store current controls values
    textBox1Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
    textBox2Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
    textBox3Value = Me.TextBox3.Value
    textBox4Value = Me.TextBox4.Value
    textBox5Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
    textBox6Value = Me.TextBox6.Value
    textBox7Value = Me.TextBox7.Value
    textBox8Value = Me.TextBox8.Value

    ' No need to activate stuff
    With targetSheet
        ' Insert a row after row 2
        .Range(targetSheetTopRow & ":" & targetSheetTopRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow

        ' Add cells values
        .Cells(targetSheetTopRow, 1).Value = textBox1Value
        .Cells(targetSheetTopRow, 2).Value = textBox2Value
        .Cells(targetSheetTopRow, 3).Value = textBox3Value
        .Cells(targetSheetTopRow, 4).Value = textBox4Value
        .Cells(targetSheetTopRow, 5).Value = textBox5Value
        .Cells(targetSheetTopRow, 6).Value = textBox6Value
        .Cells(targetSheetTopRow, 7).Value = textBox7Value
        .Cells(targetSheetTopRow, 8).Value = textBox8Value
    End With

    With homeSheet
        ' Insert a row after row 2
        .Range(homeSheetTopRow & ":" & homeSheetTopRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrBelow

        ' Add cells values
        .Cells(homeSheetTopRow, 1).Value = textBox1Value
        .Cells(homeSheetTopRow, 2).Value = textBox2Value
        .Cells(homeSheetTopRow, 3).Value = textBox3Value
        .Cells(homeSheetTopRow, 4).Value = textBox4Value
        .Cells(homeSheetTopRow, 5).Value = textBox5Value
        .Cells(homeSheetTopRow, 6).Value = textBox6Value
        .Cells(homeSheetTopRow, 7).Value = textBox7Value
        .Cells(homeSheetTopRow, 8).Value = textBox8Value
        .Cells(homeSheetTopRow, 9).Value = Date
        .Cells(homeSheetTopRow, 10).Value = TimeValue(Now)
        .Cells(homeSheetTopRow, 11).Value = textBox9Value
    End With

    ' Clear control's values
    Me.TextBox1.Value = vbNullString
    Me.TextBox2.Value = vbNullString
    Me.TextBox3.Value = vbNullString
    Me.TextBox4.Value = vbNullString

    ' Alert user
    MsgBox ("Item Added Successfully.")

    ' Goto...
    homeSheet.Activate
    homeSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works or you need more help

Comment: It did work thanks. The only thing I changed was to add the value of the combo box as the value in the first cell, but it was very easy to understand and work with, thank you!

Comment: All I want to know is, instead of copying the cell's formatting from the top, how do I copy the cell's format from the bottom? Because the new data has the same formatting and borders as the headers